# C Code running fine on ideone, but getting WA in spoj

Tags: c

http://www.spoj.com/problems/MORENA/
Getting WA in spoj, running fine otherwise on ideone, for the test cases. any idea?
Earlier i wrote this in java, was getting NZEC. Wrote this in C then.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    long num[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%ld",&num[i]);
    }

    int flag;
    int l;
    for(l=0;l<n;l++){
        if(num[l+1] > num[l]){
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        else if(num[l+1] < num[l]){
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    int count = 1,k;

    for(k =0; k<n-1; k++){
        if(flag){
            if (num[k+1] > num[k]){
                count++;
                flag = 0;
            }
            else if(num[k+1]==num[k]){
                flag = 1;
            }
            else if(num[k+1]<num[k]){
                //count++;
                flag=1;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(num[k+1] < num[k]){
                count++;
                flag = 1;
            }
            else if(num[k+1]==num[k]){
                flag = 0;
            }
            else if(num[k+1]>num[k]){
                //count++;
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't assume everyone knows what "WA" and "NZEC" mean. I certainly don't.

Comment: Mini SPOJ Glossary: SPOJ: Sphere Online Judge (a programming problem/puzzle/contest site), WA: Wrong Answer, NZEC: Non-Zero Exit Code, TLE: Time limit Exceeded

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I suggest editing that into the question.

Comment: IMO `long` is not recommended since it's 32 bits on Windows and 64 bits on most Linux/Unix implementations. C standard only specifies that long has **at least 32 bits** and you can't know how long is `long` in the judge's compiler. Assuming it's 64 bits may lead to severe overflows. If you need 64-bit type you should use `long long` which is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits instead, or use `int64_t` in `stdint.h`. Note that if I didn't read MichaelBurr's comment above I would think that WA is warning. Don't assume everyone knows what you said

Answer (score 1):

Wait what, MANY problems here.
Here are few, first:

```
  int n,i;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  long num[n];
```

isn't possible (or isn't supposed to be possible at least) to declare an array in the size of a certain variable, use [malloc()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) for that by doing so:

```
long* num = malloc(sizeof(long)*n);
```

Another problem, is that you cross the boundary of the array in the first loop, which is weird because you took care of it in the second one :P
Just change: `for(l = 0 ; l < n ; l++)` to `for(l = 0 ; l < n-1 ; l++)` as in your IF statement you use the array l+1 element, and when l is n-1 you actually test n-1 element compared to the Nth one - which isn't in the boundary of your array.
Other than that the code seems okay.

Comment: VLA is available since C99, but you have to explitcitly specify `--std=c99`

Comment: Lu'u - I know, but it's not correct in original (in my compiler you don't need to specify --std=c99 though) and I'm not sure what site runs what...

Comment: Yes I mean you can't assume anything if don't know exactly the compiler and the compile flags. Using only what is guaranteed is better

Answer (score 0):

The question has strong bonds with [competitive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_programming). Usually there is a problem displayed and user is expected to submit code which gives expected output for tested input for [online judge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_judge), and [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/) being one of them. And actually there is sample input and sample output displayed an almost all problems. So your code would give same output as shown in sample output for problem's sample input in [ideone](http://ideone.com/), but your code is tested to huge amount of data in online judge and that would result in NZEC.